# VB6 issue with NULL

Tags: parameters, null, vb6

I'm working on an application in VB6. I came across what seems to be a small issue, however it is annoying and I am unable to fix it. What I'm doing is trying to pass 2 values to a function....

```
Private Sub cmdSearch2P_Click()
    Call AxisSearch(2, cboDiagId)
End Sub
```

This is the function I'm passing it to...

```
Private Sub AxisSearch(plngAxis As Long, pcbo As ComboBox)
```

What's happening is `cboDiagID` is a NULL value which the function does not accept.
In order for it to work, it needs to be "". I don't know why, but I'm working off another application where they have a similar function. So I tried to do something like

```
Private Sub cmdSearch2P_Click()
    If IsNull(cboDiagID) Then
         cbodiagID = ""
    End if
    Call AxisSearch(2, cboDiagId)
End Sub
```

But it's still passing it as NULL. I know "" is Null however, is there a way to make it so it doesn't say NULL and instead is ""?

EDIT: it looks like the other application is using VB6 combobox, and the application I'm editing uses combobox 2.0 control. Is that why the issue?

Comment: ANyone? the slightest clue?

Comment: `""` is not `Null`, `Null` is not `Nothing`, `Nothing` is not `Empty`, `Empty` is not `vbNullString`, and `vbNullString` is not `""`. What is the type of `cboDiagID`?

Comment: The line `cbodiagID = ""` may not *set `cbodiagID` to a NULL value*. If `cbodiagID` is a combo box, then the line `cbodiagID = ""` sets the default property of `cbodiagID` to "". AFAICR the default property is `Text` so the line is equivalent to `cbodiagID.Text = ""`. Default properties are a classic gotcha in VB6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer your original question: first, `""` *isn't* `Null`, it's an empty string, which is not the same thing.  If you want to turn a `Null` into an empty string, just add an empty string to it: `Null & ""` evaluates to `""`.

This can be a handy trick.  It comes up a lot in situations where you're trying to populate a control (say, a label or text box) with a value from a database table.  For example (assume txtMyBox is a text box and rs is an ADO Recordset object):

```
txtMyBox = rs.Fields("myField")
```

Now, if the field doesn't contain any data, this will throw an error, since you can't set a text box's value to `Null`.  To fix the problem, you could do this:

```
If Not IsNull(rs.Fields("myField")) Then
    txtMyBox = rs.Fields("myField")
Else
    txtMyBox = ""
End If
```

This is cumbersome.  You could streamline it by using the ternary operator:

```
txtMyBox = IIf (Not IsNull(rs.Fields("myField")), rs.Fields("myField"), "")
```

Which is better, but still cumbersome.  Fortunately, you can also just do this:

```
txtMyBox = rs.Fields("myField") & ""
```

Because concatenating an empty string to a string has no effect on it, and concatenating an empty string to a null value gives an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It doesn't matter if it's NULL or "", because the combobox that's in place is combobox 2.0, I couldn't just pass it as combobox in my function, but this fixed it..

```
Private Sub AxisSearch(plngAxis As Long, pcbo As msforms.ComboBox)
```

more specifically msforms.combobox