# How do I programmatically delete all xlCellTypeBlank in Excel where the cell is EMPTY not Blank (i.e. the cell is a null string) in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, office-interop

I have a range of null strings in Col AA (as a result of a copy paste special value in Excel), the formula that I  copy/paste special value in col AA is `"=if(Z6<1,"",Z6)"`. Excel treats null string cells as empty cells, not blank cells.

I either need to convert the empty cells/null strings to blanks via some excel formulaic solution or change my below c# code to delete empty cells not blank cells.  If I could somehow convert all of those cells with null strings to blank cells this code would work:

`var deleteRange = plWS.get_Range("AA6", "AA149");
deleteRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete();`

I'm implementing this code on multiple sheets, so I'm trying to do this without having to loop through all rows for efficiency/times sake.

I'm open to Excel formula solutions as well as C# programming solutions.

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you want because of the mixed terms. There are no null strings in Excel, and Empty cells is exactly the same as Blank cells. A cell containing a zero-length string, `""`, is neither blank nor empty (which is the same thing). The function that detects actually blank cells is `ISBLANK()`.

Comment: @GSerg You are incorrect. They empty and blank are different in excel. Let's say you have the following formula in col Z6 in excel:   ' =""  '    . Now let's say you paste special values cell Z6, now let's say you have the following formula in cell AA6 in excel: ISBLANK(Z6). The value of cell AA6 will be False because Z6 is empty, not blank (ie it is a null string). I tested it and confirmed via research this is the case.

Comment: You seem to be using the word "empty" in its everyday sense (i.e. "appears empty on the screen"). It does not really work for two reasons - first, there can be a lot of data in the cell and it would still appear empty on the screen because of the formatting pattern applied, and second, `Empty` is a special value of type `Variant/Empty`. `ISBLANK` specifically detects cells that have the value of `Empty`. There are other possible [empty-ish values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057665/vb6-issue-with-null#comment61664803_37057665) too.

Comment: A cell that contains absolutely anything, including a zero-length string, is *not* `Empty`. "Blank" is a complete synonym of a cell that contains `Empty`. As for "null strings", they do not exist on an Excel sheet. It's either `Empty` or `""`, but never `Null` or `vbNullString`.

Answer (score 0):

Excel distinguishes between empty(aka null) and blank. If you're trying to delete empty rows with something like the below:

```
deleteRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete();
```

it is impossible because this deletes BLANK rows only, not empty/null rows.The easiest way to address this issue is to use a find and replace function in c# like the below FIND AND REPLACE to turn your cells into BLANKS first. i.e. even though you are replacing with "", it's actually returning BLANK:

```
var deleteRange = loopWS.get_Range("AA6", "AA150");
deleteRange.Cells.Replace(What: "0", Replacement: "");
```