# Blank cells with value

Tags: excel

I have a lot of Cells in my book that don't have any value but still count toward the "Count". When i try to navigate with Ctrl and arrow keys these cells also "interrupt" the scrolling, which is quite annoying. When i select these cells and delete them they don't have a "value" anymore (also works if I edit the text and press Enter on each one), but it's a decently sized document with quite a lot of these. I wonder what is the cause and if there's a way to fix it.

"Count: 14" in empty cells:

[image: 1]

Comment: There are characters inside those cells, so they are not blank.Type =LEN(A2) (the right cell reference), next to them, and you'll see how many characters are inside those cells.

Comment: @sophods The LEN returns 0.

Comment: This is very strange. If the len returns 0, then it shouldn't stop there when you use Cntrl + arrow to navigate..

Comment: Some formats result in blank cells being treated the same as non-null cells (such as borders) in some instances. This could also be ghost data as result of past error. To correct, highlight area[s] with issue, navigate to home tab > clear > clear all

Comment: @urdearboy clear all works, just like pressing Delete. Is there any way to select all of these cells so i can either Clear or Delete them?

Comment: What happens if you run COUNTBLANK() on the same range?

Comment: Like I said, highlight the affected area all at once. Not cell by cell. There are a few solutions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881003/use-find-replace-to-clear-vbnullstring) outlining same issue

Comment: I usually just started a new book when this issue popped up. Sometimes the book is corrupt but it never fully breaks and this issue just keeps coming up over and over. Any chance you are pasting data here from some external file (CSV?) regularly? That can sometimes import strange characters and lead to this. To avoid, try to only paste values (right click > paste special > paste values)

Comment: @urdearboy I will try to find a solution to select everything. I have tried to create a new book and copy pasting values into it but it still has the same issue. I have made several VLookups from other documents (not sure if CSV, maybe some of them).

Comment: @PaulWilson COUNTBLANK returns 1.

Comment: CTRL + A and then clear it all....

Comment: @urdearboy that will also erase my data. Worst case scenario I have to go column by column and clear the blanks. Was hoping for a cleaner solution, maybe in the link you gave me, which is helpful thank you.

Comment: Do you know any VBA?

Comment: What is the top of the range highlighted in our photo? (What column/row?)

Comment: A cell that contains an empty string is not blank. A cell that contains a formula that returns an empty string is not blank either. A cell is blank only when it truly contains nothing, as opposed to something of zero length.

Answer (score 1):

The `UsedRange` property of a worksheet also includes the cells with ghost data that you are seeing which can help you dynamically clear the right cells. Note this will clear **everything** from the blank cells. That includes comments, formatting, etc so just make sure that isn't a problem for other cells that don't have the ghost data problem.

1. Loop through each cell in the `UsedRange` and look for cells with `Len = 0` and `HasFormula = False` i.e. your blanks to be cleared
2. Add these cells (no characters) to a `Union` *(collection of cells)*
3. Once the loop is complete, clear the `Union` which will hopefully resolve your issue

---

```
Sub Clear()

Dim Target As Range
Dim ClearMe As Range

For Each Target In Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    If Len(Target) = 0 And Not Target.HasFormula Then
        If Not ClearMe Is Nothing Then
            Set ClearMe = Union(ClearMe, Target)
        Else
            Set ClearMe = Target
        End If
    End If
Next Target

If Not ClearMe Is Nothing Then ClearMe.Clear

End Sub
```

---

*If you want to test this before running the macro on your entire sheet then replace the `UsedRange` with the actual range you showed us in your photo. For instance, `For Each Target In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")` (idk the actual range). Once the macro is done, see if that same range shows you a count once it's highlighted*

Comment: A great answer................I like using `Union()`

Answer (score 1):

If cell **A2** appears to be empty, and  **A2** has zero length, in another cell enter:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<>0,"stuff",IF(COUNTA(A2)=0,"genuine empty","null character"))
```

This will allow you to distinguish:

1. characters in the cell
2. nothing at all in the cell
3. a formula returning *Null* in the cell or a *Null* constant
    *(by Null I mean a **zero length string**)*

If you want to `Clear` these cells, run this short macro:

```
Sub diogo()
    Dim cell As Range, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
            If wf.CountA(cell) = 1 Then
                cell.Clear
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel cells [never contain `Null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944546/11683), and `If CountA() = 1` would probably be more readable as `If Not IsEmpty()`.

Comment: Is `wf.CountA(cell)` counting the length of formula? If so, very good catch + addition. Should have been added to my solution

Comment: @urdearboy No, it counts the number of non-blank cells in `cell`. Given that `cell` is one cell, the answer can be either 0 or 1.

Comment: I must be tired. Dont know why I didn't see that. Ive never created a variable for worksheet function so the wf threw me ha. Then the issue is that this (and mine) potentially clear formulas that may output null such as `IFERROR( something, "")`

Comment: @GSerg  Thank you very much!  I will use `IsEmpty()` from now on.  I know ***Null*** is not the proper term for a zero length string.......Is there a proper term???

Comment: @Gary'sStudent A "zero length string" is pretty proper, so would be an "empty string". Which, again, is [not the same as `Empty`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057665/vb6-issue-with-null#comment61664803_37057665) either...

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a way to ask this question that produced any easy answer for turning "NONBLANK" cells into "EMPTY" cells for plotting of a table column. "NONBLANK" cells kept getting plotted as 0.0.
I found something that worked:
in the table, sort on that column (that little down arrow in the header is mucho good); all of the "NONBLANK", "NONEMPTY" cells will be collected together; Select all of these cells and delete them (with Delete key, NOT with Delete option in drop-down menu); sort the table by the usual key column.
Plot looks great!